# Can I make ASP.NET MVC Html.RouteLink() return a url for my home page without an ID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, html-helper

I've got a single route in my `Global.asax.vb` page like this...

```
Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "IdOnly", _
        "{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Page", _
                  .action = "Details", _
                  .id = "7"} _
    )
End Sub
```

That `id` is for my home page.  It's displayed when someone navigates to my: `http://example.com/`

But, this also works:  `http://example.com/7`

I'd like to have no links anywhere on my site to the address with `id` of 7.  But, the `Html.RouteLink()` function generates those.

For a view Model that's a child of the home page…

```
<%=Html.RouteLink(Model.Parent.Title, _
                  "IdOnly", _
                  New With {.id = Model.Parent.Id})%>
```

…generates the following anchor tag:

```
<a href="/7">Home</a>
```

How can I override the `href` generated by the `Html.RouteLink()` function for my home page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a new route before your "IdOnly" route for the home page:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    "HomePage", _
    "", _
    New With {.controller = "Page", _
              .action = "Details", _
              .id = "7"} _
)
```

`RouteLink` will use the first matched mapping in the routing table to generate the link.